# Card Game: Probability, Combinatorics, - 52 suit picks,12 correct, four suit, not dependant

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Using a standard deck of cards (52 cards, four suits), one card is picked to guess the correct suit only and then replaced with the deck shuffled.  This is repeated 52 times.  If 12 cards out of the entire deck where picked correctly, what is the probability of this event?  The order upon which the cards are correctly picked does not matter, just the final number of the correct guesses.  The suit can change on each pick, but should not change the outcome as their are 13 cards of each suit.  Side Note: Eventually I must calculate this for all combinations from 0 correct to 52 correct to three significant digits.  Originally tried to calculate with algebra, now trying combinatorics.  The chance of each individual pick being right is 0.25, however only 12 correct picks for 52 separate events makes what probability?

Using the formula of correct picks over total picks, would this be correct: 
(52 over 12) divided by (52 over 52) * 52.  .

Thanks for any input you supply in advance!  Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is with replacement, use $bin\sim(52,0.25)$

$Pr(X = 12) = \dbinom{52}{12}\times0.25^{12}\times0.75^{40}$

*PS:*

Since you need to compute for all values from $0$ to $52$, the general formula is:

$Pr(X = x) = \dbinom{52}{x}\times 0.25^x\times0.75^{52-x}$,

but why don't you just use a binomial calculator, e.g. [here](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/stats/bernoulli.html) ?